# How To deploy Dropwizard Web Services in Tomcat Server

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, tomcat, dropwizard

I am facing a problem to deploy drop wizard services in tomcat server,

I have created my web services in drop wizard framework which use jetty server in default, but here I want to deploy my web services in tomcat server so is there any way that how to deploy Drop wizard created services in tomcat environment.

Because drpo wizard use .jar file instead of .war file so is there any way to convert .jar to .war for deploying it in another server.

Please give your valuable answer I am facing these problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the below link points out, its not overly recommended as a pattern but if you use:
https://github.com/twilio/wiztowar

You can convert your jar to a war for deployment to an application server.  Comes with the fairly big warning attached that its not overly tested.

It might be the time to look at why you are using drop wizard if you plan to deploy to a tomcat app server. It goes against the core principals of the framework to a degree.

Spring boot is another option which can embed jetty or tomcat or produce a standard war.

Comment: Actually earlier I started creating webservices through webwizard at that time there was no issue for deployment  but now requirement has been changed and I want to deploy them in tomcat for some reason. so will there any problem for converting jar to war.

Comment: Its hard to say without testing, I have used the converter in the past and it has worked ok.  Your mileage my vary tho if following this approach i would recommend thorough testing.